# Salesforce Certified Platform Developer 2.1 (Multiple choice)

Tags: certification

What are the differences at a high level(*with respect to content, topic etc*) between the transition exam for 501.1 -> SCPD 2.1 and a fresh SCPD 2.1 multiple choice exam ?

Are they both the same ?

Comment: Anything else you'd still like to know ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the email that the certification team send out when they introduced the new exams [the transition exam from a fully certified advanced developer is 16 multiple choice questions to be taken in 30 minutes with a passing score required of 63%](http://www.salesforce.com/campaigns/success-services/advanced-force-developer-certification.jsp). If you have only passed the advanced developer multiple choice part, you'll need to do a harder (60q) transition exam to transition to the same level in the SCPD process I believe.

[Knowledge artickle](http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/FAQ-Developer-Certification-Transition-Process)

If you were not already in process of getting advanced developer certified, platform developer 1 becomes a prerequisite for the standard route to achieve the platform developer 2 certification.

[Certification site](http://certification.salesforce.com/platform-developers)